# IF-statement in excel, check if cell start with a variable number

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

The function that i'm trying to get to work is this:

```
Sub knapp()
Dim counter As Integer
counter = 200
Rows("7").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromBelow
For counter = 200 To 800
    If Sheets("Ark1").Range("C3").Value = "counter*" Then
        Sheets("Ark2").Range("C" & counter).Copy
        Sheets("Ark1").Range("E7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues,    Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
         :=False, Transpose:=False
        Sheets("Ark1").Range("E7").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        Sheets("Ark2").Range("D" & counter).Copy
        Sheets("Ark1").Range("F7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
Next counter
End Sub
```

The cell C3 contains a number and a text, i.e "240 - Test text text". The value changes, but the format of it is always as above
If C3 starts with 240 then I want it to copy the corresponding cell from the other sheet. 
The copying part works, but the IF-statement is the issue. 
I dont know how to check if C3 starts with the variable counter.

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Add the code to your post and use proper formatting on it. Most people aren't going to go to a different page to have a look at your code. Neither are they going to type in whatever code is necessary to replicate the behavior, when it would have been much simpler copying it from your post.

Comment: [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Comment: if you can check just the first number you can use this: 
=IF(LEFT(C3,1)="2","V","x")

Comment: Try [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KWqdi.png).

Answer (score -1):

Use this function:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("240",C3))
```